# Dependency Injection failing to start function

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

Azure function runs fine locally, when deployed to Azure via Deployment Centre (or Publish), the function fails to start and the Azure dashboard displays

```
    Error:

    The function runtime is unable to start. System.Linq: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: source.
    Session Id: 353349c4b2c14b2399acd9fa26e79c0b

    Timestamp: 2019-07-01T20:29:51.503Z
```

I am developing a Timer Triggered function that processes data periodically from a database (using EntityFramework). The function posts messages to a StorageQueue. I've tested locally, all seems to work, the function runs, access DB, processes data and posts messages to StorageQueue, no issues.

When I deploy to Azure, I get this error message as shown above displayed in dashboard.

I was able to Attach Debugger to the function in VS2019 and found that an Exception is getting thrown in namespace `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection`, file `ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs`.

The actual function is

```
public Type[] GetStartupTypes()
        {
            IEnumerable<Type> startupTypes = GetExtensionsStartupTypesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return startupTypes
                .Distinct(new TypeNameEqualityComparer())
                .ToArray();
        }
```

It seems that `startupTypes` is `null`, so when `.Distinct()` is called, exception is thrown.

I've break pointed the function and I can see that on my machine `startupTypes` contains 3 items:

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.AzureStorageWebJobsStartup
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.ServiceBusWebJobsStartup
- PlexusDataFeeds.Startup

Additional info:

- SDK, Micorsoft.NETCode.App (2.0.0)
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (1.0.29)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (2.2.4)

Startup.cs

```
 class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {

            string SqlConnection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PlexusContextConnection");
            var serviceProvider = builder.Services.AddDbContext<PlexusContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(SqlConnection))
            .AddLogging()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
```

functions.json

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.29",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *",
      "useMonitor": true,
      "runOnStartup": false,
      "name": "myTimer"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/PlexusDataFeeds.dll",
  "entryPoint": "PlexusDataFeeds.DataFeedSelector.DataFeedSelector.Run"
}
```

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.0.6]"
  }
}
```

extensions.json (from Azure)

```
{
  "extensions":[
    { "name": "AzureStorage", "typeName":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.AzureStorageWebJobsStartup, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"},
    { "name": "ServiceBus", "typeName":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.ServiceBusWebJobsStartup, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"},
    { "name": "Startup", "typeName":"PlexusDataFeeds.Startup, PlexusDataFeeds, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
  ]
}
```

**edit**

The actual exception is `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'` on `startupTypes`.

**edit 2**
I removed the `Willezone.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DependencyInjection` NuGet package and using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` instead.

Still the same fault.

Comment: Why not use this nuget `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`

Comment: @HariHaran, I have re-written then `Configure()` function and removed the `Willezone.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. I could not directly find the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. I could only find the `Microsoft.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. Is it the same?

With all these changes, I am still seeing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I ended up not using Dependency Injection and initialising objects in the functions I need.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a deployment issue, can you check if when you release the function, all needed binaries are there in release next to function executable.

Comment: Also, I do not see in code initializing the interface in service startup.